# Deploy Spark Scala on Cloudera or EMR

Tags: scala, apache-spark, deployment, cloudera, emr

I created a sample app (Snippet 1), i deploy it on Cloudera using (sbt assembly ) , it works.

```
 object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Pi")
    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)
    val slices = if (args.length > 0) args(0).toInt else 2
    val n = math.min(100000L * slices, Int.MaxValue).toInt // avoid overflow
    val count = spark
      .parallelize(1 until n, slices)
      .map { i =>
        val x = random * 2 - 1
        val y = random * 2 - 1
        if (x * x + y * y < 1) 1 else 0
      }
      .reduce(_ + _)
    println("Pi is roughly " + 4.0 * count / n)
    spark.stop()
  }
  }
```

So i want to read a json file & print the schema, so obviously i created a new spark session,

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("Test")
      .getOrCreate
    spark.read.json(getClass.getResource("data.json").getPath)
    .printSchema()
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

This snippet won't work, because i think i shouldn't do sparkSession.builder() . But read.json is only available in the SparkSession Object.

This my command to run the jar :

```
spark-submit --master yarn-cluster path_to_jar
```

Stack trace :

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/parquet/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
17/07/20 04:15:35 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/07/20 04:15:36 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
17/07/20 04:15:36 INFO yarn.Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 1 NodeManagers
17/07/20 04:15:36 INFO yarn.Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (8192 MB per container)
17/07/20 04:15:36 INFO yarn.Client: Will allocate AM container, with 1408 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
17/07/20 04:15:36 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
17/07/20 04:15:36 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
17/07/20 04:15:36 INFO yarn.Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
17/07/20 04:15:38 WARN shortcircuit.DomainSocketFactory: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
17/07/20 04:15:38 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/lib/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.0-cdh5.10.0-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.10.0.jar -> hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/.sparkStaging/application_1500545966176_0008/spark-assembly-1.6.0-cdh5.10.0-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.10.0.jar
17/07/20 04:15:39 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/media/sf_SparkS3AirFlow/target/scala-2.11/spark-emr-test.jar -> hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/.sparkStaging/application_1500545966176_0008/spark-emr-test.jar
17/07/20 04:15:41 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-3a2fec6b-6148-49a9-9db7-7a7cca99c586/__spark_conf__2098882718740574102.zip -> hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/.sparkStaging/application_1500545966176_0008/__spark_conf__2098882718740574102.zip
17/07/20 04:15:41 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: cloudera
17/07/20 04:15:41 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: cloudera
17/07/20 04:15:41 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(cloudera); users with modify permissions: Set(cloudera)
17/07/20 04:15:41 INFO yarn.Client: Submitting application 8 to ResourceManager
17/07/20 04:15:41 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1500545966176_0008
17/07/20 04:15:42 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:15:42 INFO yarn.Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: root.cloudera
     start time: 1500549341177
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1500545966176_0008/
     user: cloudera
17/07/20 04:15:43 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:15:44 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:15:45 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:15:46 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:15:47 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:15:48 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:15:49 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:15:50 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:15:51 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:15:52 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:15:53 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:15:54 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0008 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:15:55 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0008 (state: FAILED)
17/07/20 04:15:55 INFO yarn.Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Application application_1500545966176_0008 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1500545966176_0008_000002 exited with  exitCode: 15
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1500545966176_0008/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1500545966176_0008_02_000001
Exit code: 15
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=15: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:504)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:786)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 15
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: root.cloudera
     start time: 1500549341177
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/cluster/app/application_1500545966176_0008
     user: cloudera
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1500545966176_0008 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1030)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1077)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
17/07/20 04:15:55 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
17/07/20 04:15:55 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-3a2fec6b-6148-49a9-9db7-7a7cca99c586
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ clearc^C
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ ^C
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ spark-submit --master yarn-cluster /media/sf_SparkS3AirFlow/target/scala-2.11/spark-emr-test.jar
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/parquet/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
17/07/20 04:50:03 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/07/20 04:50:04 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
17/07/20 04:50:04 INFO yarn.Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 1 NodeManagers
17/07/20 04:50:04 INFO yarn.Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (8192 MB per container)
17/07/20 04:50:04 INFO yarn.Client: Will allocate AM container, with 1408 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
17/07/20 04:50:04 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
17/07/20 04:50:04 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
17/07/20 04:50:04 INFO yarn.Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
17/07/20 04:50:06 WARN shortcircuit.DomainSocketFactory: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
17/07/20 04:50:06 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/usr/lib/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.0-cdh5.10.0-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.10.0.jar -> hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/.sparkStaging/application_1500545966176_0009/spark-assembly-1.6.0-cdh5.10.0-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.10.0.jar
17/07/20 04:50:07 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/media/sf_SparkS3AirFlow/target/scala-2.11/spark-emr-test.jar -> hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/.sparkStaging/application_1500545966176_0009/spark-emr-test.jar
17/07/20 04:50:09 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-2dbf7a93-4377-4ad1-8e78-56330ee03b7f/__spark_conf__8411937016766228982.zip -> hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/.sparkStaging/application_1500545966176_0009/__spark_conf__8411937016766228982.zip
17/07/20 04:50:09 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Caught exception 
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1281)
    at java.lang.Thread.join(Thread.java:1355)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.closeResponder(DFSOutputStream.java:951)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.endBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:689)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:878)
17/07/20 04:50:09 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: cloudera
17/07/20 04:50:09 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: cloudera
17/07/20 04:50:09 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(cloudera); users with modify permissions: Set(cloudera)
17/07/20 04:50:09 INFO yarn.Client: Submitting application 9 to ResourceManager
17/07/20 04:50:09 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1500545966176_0009
17/07/20 04:50:10 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0009 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:50:10 INFO yarn.Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: root.cloudera
     start time: 1500551409216
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1500545966176_0009/
     user: cloudera
17/07/20 04:50:11 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0009 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:50:12 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0009 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:50:13 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0009 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:50:14 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0009 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:50:15 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0009 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:50:16 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0009 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:50:17 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0009 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:50:18 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0009 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:50:19 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0009 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:50:20 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0009 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:50:21 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0009 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/07/20 04:50:22 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1500545966176_0009 (state: FAILED)
17/07/20 04:50:22 INFO yarn.Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Application application_1500545966176_0009 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1500545966176_0009_000002 exited with  exitCode: 15
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1500545966176_0009/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1500545966176_0009_02_000001
Exit code: 15
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=15: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:504)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:786)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 15
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: root.cloudera
     start time: 1500551409216
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/cluster/app/application_1500545966176_0009
     user: cloudera
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1500545966176_0009 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1030)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1077)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
17/07/20 04:50:22 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
17/07/20 04:50:22 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-2dbf7a93-4377-4ad1-8e78-56330ee03b7f
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$
```

Yarn log of the app_id :

```
Container: container_1500545966176_0011_02_000001 on quickstart.cloudera_44248
================================================================================
LogType:stderr
Log Upload Time:Thu Jul 20 05:02:55 -0700 2017
LogLength:4104
Log Contents:
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/zookeeper/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/flume-ng/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/lib/parquet/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
17/07/20 05:02:45 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
17/07/20 05:02:49 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: ApplicationAttemptId: appattempt_1500545966176_0011_000002
17/07/20 05:02:53 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: yarn,cloudera
17/07/20 05:02:53 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: yarn,cloudera
17/07/20 05:02:53 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(yarn, cloudera); users with modify permissions: Set(yarn, cloudera)
17/07/20 05:02:53 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Starting the user application in a separate Thread
17/07/20 05:02:53 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Waiting for spark context initialization...
17/07/20 05:02:53 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.config(SparkSession.scala:780)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.master(SparkSession.scala:833)
    at Main$.main(Main.scala:8)
    at Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:552)
17/07/20 05:02:53 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;)
17/07/20 05:02:53 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Boxed Error
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$.resolver(Promise.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$.scala$concurrent$impl$Promise$$resolveTry(Promise.scala:47)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:244)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.tryFailure(Promise.scala:112)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryFailure(Promise.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:570)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.config(SparkSession.scala:780)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.master(SparkSession.scala:833)
    at Main$.main(Main.scala:8)
    at Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:552)
17/07/20 05:02:53 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with FAILED (diag message: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;)
17/07/20 05:02:53 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Deleting staging directory .sparkStaging/application_1500545966176_0011
17/07/20 05:02:53 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called

LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time:Thu Jul 20 05:02:55 -0700 2017
LogLength:0
Log Contents:
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong with this and how to fix it ?

Thank you

Comment: what's the error ? can you print it's stack trace ?

Comment: @dumitru please i ve just edited the question with the stack trace :)

Comment: Can you paste from your sbt file, seems like the scala version that you are compiling the jar and scala version from where you run the jar (cloudera) are not the same

Comment: Yes you're right, i use spark 2.0.2, but in cloudera use spark 1.6. I'm upgrading spark now :) , i'll be back when i tested it with the new version

Comment: Cloudera is also providing their own Spark dependency packages, which you should use, to avoid dependency conflicts.

Comment: Yes, right use cloudera repositories for spark dependencies

Comment: Yes you were right, i upgraded spark, and it works like a charm, thank you